# Regular expression dilemma

Tags: regex

I'm trying for a few hours to write a pattern for some matching algorithm and I can't manage to find something for the following issue: given the example "my_name_is", I need to extract all words individually, as well as the whole expression. Consider that it may be a list of n examples, some that can be matched, some that cannot be matched.

"my_name_is" => ["my", "name", "is", "my_name_is"]

How can I do this, how should the regexp look like? Looking forward for your answers, thank you!

Comment: Does it necessarily need to be a regex?

Comment: Split on _, append the original, and roll on.

Comment: You need to do this in two steps. First match the whole string, then extract the parts.

Comment: A single regexp can't match multiple things at once. And if you use a capture group followed by a quantifier to match multiple occurrences, it only captures the first occurrence.

Comment: I understand, I will see what solution I'll find, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions are patterns used to match a string of characters. We usually use them to validate a string of characters, or to find and replace a specific pattern within text.

Here, it seems the outcome you're looking for is an array of strings that have been *split* using an underscore. Regex isn't what you're looking for.

Implementation would change based on language, but consider the following code:

```
function stringToArray(myStr)
{
    words = str_split(myStr, '_');
    return array_merge(words, [myStr]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use re.findall with the following as your regex:

```
([^_]+)+?
```

This should match all sets of consecutive characters that don't contain the underscore.

As for the whole thing? You already have it, so there's no reason to regex the whole string